# Unable to Connect to GCP VM Via Visual Studio Code Remote SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-extensions, openssh

I've been trying unsuccessfully for some time to connect vscode to a vm instance in google cloud platform using the SSH Keys and the Remote-SSH extension for vscode.

As per the tutorials and documentation examples this is my current config file (ip and username blanks for security):

```
Host ipaddress
    User myusername
    HostName ipaddress
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dev-env-open-ssh-format-privkey
```

The config file is located in the `~/.ssh` folder. When I attempt the connection I get the message.

```
Could not establish a connection to "ipaddress".
```

From the output terminal (I can't seem to get all the text as the pop up dialog with the fail message doesn't allow me to get access to copy the log). But I notice this line in the output

```
> no such identity: C:\\My Username Has a Space/\\.ssh\dev-env-open-ssh-format-key: No such file or directory
>username@ipaddress: Permission denied (publickey).
```

The slashes are oriented differently based on what I try but the message remains the same more or less. I don't get why there are more slashes in the error message than what was specified in the config file.

What I have tried:

- Changing the slashes from forward to back
- Exporting the privkey to ssh format (as I saw on the code.visualstudio.com/docs...)
- The original privKey from puttyGen
- Specifying the full path to the key - C:\Users\My Username Has a Space.ssh\privKey
- The above point with forward slashes and backslashes, with and without surrounding double quotes.
- Purged the settings using: **Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host**
- I tried putting the privKey directly on the root of the C drive to rule out space errors within the username.
- Restarting local computer (desperation)
- Restarting vm

**What works**:

- Connecting the the VM via Putty (with the original privKey)
- Connecting to the VM via FileZilla (with the original privKey)
- Note: Both of the above methods connect to the VM then prompt for a password. I supply the passcode then I'm in.

I don't get a prompt for the passcode using vscode but I imagine without the privKey it won't get hat far.

I'm using Windows 10 with vs code 1.60.1. The VM is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Remote - SSH v0.65.8.

I'm not sure what other information is relevant to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

For the configuration file, you should use the following:

```
Host your-instance-name
HostName external-ip-address
Identity files C:\path\to\your\key\this_is_the_key_name
User the-user-you-choose-for-the-key
```

You need to use a key in the `.pub` format (you can install Git and create a key with `ssh-keygen.exe`), because if you have generated a key with PuTTy in the `.ppk` format, this won't work.

**Another thing:** When you try to connect to your instance, make sure that `know_host` in the file in `C:\Users\yourname\\.ssh` doesn't have a connection inside of it that hasn't previously worked.

Let us know if you managed to connect.

Comment: what would be the equivalent in Ubuntu - do you know?

Comment: @DanErez In Ubuntu you directly generate ssh-key in `.pub` format, so you should just change the path to your key.
Have you already tried to do this?